# Java Socket Create a Room for multiple player

Tags: java, sockets

I have a question but dont have a answer, i wanna create a application client/server

Server can retrieve multiple clients connect, but when client want to create a room for play a game like gomoku for 2 players and limit access just only 2 players can access this room and other player can access but they just only view. And when a room is available it mean this room not full (it just has a 1 player and need one to player a game).

Could you give me a way to do that (create a room, limit access...) by using java socket

Thank you

Comment: Sockets solve only the server/client communication. All the rest is up to you and is too general. You need to sit and think how you could do it and come back when you have specific questions. Also, sockets are old and there are plenty of resources about how to use them and what they do.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you read the [faq] and [ask] to understand the types of questions that can be posted on SO.  Your question does not fit in the guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question assumes many things that are too broad for a single answer.  But perhaps a simple example will help you answer some questions.

Here is a nice example of a chat program I found written in java, using sockets: http://pguides.net/java-tutorial/tcp-clientserver-chat/

Try to get this up and running, and I think you will be a good way along trying to assess what your next steps are.